# Извлечь имена ресурсов

Tags: c#, локализация

Делаю мультиязычность, как советует MSDN, с помощью ресурсов. Создал следующие файлы ресурсов:

- Strings.resx
- Strings.fr-FR.resx
- Strings.ru-RU.resx
- Strings.uk-UA.resx

Потом задаю CultureInfo и извлекаю локализованные строки.
Как программно узнать, какие языки у меня поддерживаются? Как получить список имён ресурсов?

Comment: А зачем вам динамическое получение списка имён ресурсов? Если вдруг окажется ресурс, о котором ваша программа не знала на этапе компиляции, что она с ним будет делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Узнать это можно думаю только попытавшись получить ресурсы для того, или иного языка. Примерно так:

```
// Получаем список всех CultureInfo:
var allCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);

// Создаем ResourceManager:
var resMgr = new ResourceManager(typeof(MyResourcesClass));

// Получаем все CultureInfo для которых удалось получить ресурсы.
var supportedCultures = allCultures.Where(culture => resMgr.GetResourceSet(culture, true, false) != null);
```

Код не тестировал, но что-то мне подсказываем что это не самый лучший выход, и значительно проще хранить список поддерживаемых языков в файле конфигурации.